# Citadel Mailserver Installation floods every root console with error messages

Tags: ubuntu, console, citadel

I have installed Citadel (`apt-get install citadel-suite`) on my Ubuntu 12.04 Box. I configured it for LDAP authentication. After the installation every root console got flooded with error messages of the following pattern:

```
DB: PANIC: Invalid argument
bdb(): PANIC: Invalid argument
bdb(): txn_commit: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
DB: not a restored transaction
```

The only way to stop this was to kill the 'citserver' process.

Is there a way to stop those messages from flooding my console?
What causes this error and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the cause of this myself:

The Citadel package of Ubuntu 12.04 is broken for some systems as it says here:

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/citadel/+bug/911732
```

I will now try to upgrade to 14.04 or install citadel manually...

Update: I was not able to upgrade to 14.04 because of my server provider. I instead reinstalled the machine with debian 7 -> works like a charm...